# "обновился" рабочий стол, windows

Tags: windows

чтож, вчера работала за компьютером и ничего подозрительного не заметила. сегодня — черный фон и три ярлыка: хром, мой компютер и корзина. файлы на дисках с и д вроде не тронуты. просмотрела корзину — там удалены файлы включительно моими руками до вчерашнего дня. у меня на рабочем столе были важные папки. глупо, знаю, но для оптимизации труда было нормально. в последнее время ничего не скачивала. помогите, пожалуйста, кто в курсе что делать.[image: рабочий стол]

P.S.по пути если перейти С/Пользователи/Рабочий стол (примерно помню, извините) — папка пустая. Профиль аккаунта мой.

P.S.v2 проблема решена, я просто не разобралась как выбрать правильный ответ. в общем и целом, я думаю что просто винда обновилась да и все. спасибо всем кто помог, :D

Comment: Надеюсь тут не будут писать "надо было ставить linux" 

Comment: Проверьте что профиль ваш. У меня после какого-то обновления появился профиль гостя и под него залогинило и получилось похоже -- стандартная тема рабочего стола и несколько стандартных ярлыков

Comment: А если зайти в папку рабочего стола через проводник? Там тоже самое? `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop`, ну или `C:\Пользователи\Пользователь\Рабочий стол`. Попробуйте включить показ скрытых файлов

Comment: увы, профиль мой..

Comment: Ищите папки и файлы по известным именам или их фрагментам по всем дискам. Вариантов-то собственно немного - либо перемещение неловким движением мыша, либо злонамеренное действие. Компьютер - сетевой? Можете попробовать поиск удалённых файлов - скажем, с помощью Recuva portable. Но пока старайтесь по возможности ничего на диск C: не писать и не устанавливать.